# Change color or add indicator on airline if I modified a file on git repository

Tags: git, vim-fugitive, vim-airline

I want to have an indicator if I modified a file and I don't create a commit.
Any idea?

I install fugitive and is very cool but I have only the name of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git-prompt for your requirement.

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh

The comments in the script explains how to make this work.